# Determining whether list items have same length and returning last one if so

Tags: python

I'm new to programming, so hopefully I'm not asking a stupid question. I came across a practice problem, and I got most of the way through it but I'm stuck on one detail. I have words in a list, and both the words and list could be any length. I needed to figure out how to return the word with the longest length, and I was able to do that. But I also need to know if there are multiple words of the longest length, and return just the last one in the list if so.

Any guidance or reprimands would be welcome.

Edits:
The input would be a string of words separated only by spaces (no punctuation) and the output will be a single word from that string. It looks like I said I was using a list of words rather than a string, I messed up the distinction, not sure if that changes the way to approach it. Sorry for not posting the code (and not being around to check this earlier, I thought maybe it would be a day or two). What I came up with before coming here to ask for help is:

```
def longest_word(string_of_words):
    split_words = string_of_words.split(" ")
    biggest = max(split_words, key=len)
    return biggest

longest_word('red blue grey')
```

The problem itself:

> When given a string of space separated words, return the word with the longest length. If there are multiple words with the longest length, return the last instance of the word with the longest length.

Comment: share your code ,input and expected output

Comment: Please fill in some detail as to what you've tried and what is not clear to you. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Hint: you actually don't need to know if there are multiple words of the longest length; you just need to return the last word of the longest length in all cases (since if there's just one longest one, it's still the last one of the longest length). You should be able to adapt your existing program pretty easily - though we can't help unless you post it!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `max` with `len` as the key parameter.

```
max(word_list, key=len)
```

If you want to get the last longest word, You can reverse the word list first.

```
max(reversed(word_list), key=len)
```

Comment: This returns the *first* occurrence of the longest word in my test case.

Comment: @JaredGoguen I have updated my answer for get the last longest word in the list.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an interesting 2-stage list comprehension that does it (just for fun). Given the list mylist = ['longword1', 'another', 'longword2', 'more'], the following nested comprehension correctly yields 'longword2'.

```
res = [word for word in mylist if len(word) == max([len(word) for word in mylist])][-1:]
```

Answer (score 0):

So, you can use `sorted` to sort the words and provide a key. The higher values of the key will occur later in the list. If two values produce the same key, they are left in order.

```
sorted(word_list, key=len)[-1]
```

This sorts the `word_list` in order of length (using `len`) and maintains the relative order of words with the same length. Thus, the last occurrence of the longest word will be at the end of the result.

This is a quick, Pythonic solution, but it is not computationally optimal. This will use O(n*log n) where as iterating over the list explicitly and tracking the longest word will only take O(n) time.

To roll out an efficient solution:

```
def last_longest_word(word_list):
    longest_word, length = '', 0

    for word in word_list:
        test_length = len(word)
        if test_length >= length:
            longest_word, length = word, test_length

    return longest_word
```

Comment: For find the largest or smallest N items from sequence, If the N is a relatively small number, We can use heapq. If N is 1, We can use max of min. If N is about the same size of the sequence, We can use sorted and slice.